# How to prevent `rlwrap` from saving a password in an input history file?

Tags: command-line, readline

I'm using the `rlwrap` utility inside the following shell alias:

```
alias gp='rlwrap git push'
```

The purpose of this `gp` alias is to be able to use basic line editing commands such as `C-a` or `C-e` to get to the beginning or end of the command line, while I'm using the `git push` command.

I've also configured `rlwrap` to write the input history of every command I use it for, in a dedicated file (`~/.config/rlwrap/<command>_history`):

```
export RLWRAP_HOME="${HOME}/.config/rlwrap"
```

When I use the `gp` alias, I have to give my credentials, username and password, and `rlwrap` saves them in `~/.config/rlwrap/git_history`.

Is it possible to let `rlwrap` save the input history of all the commands I use, except the passwords, like for example in the `gp` alias?

Comment: Can't you set up ssh keys for the remote git server?

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you very much for your suggestion. I don't know much about git and ssh, but I will look into this as soon as I can.

Comment: For example, in github, go to your account settings and you'll see a section for "SSH keys". You can create a public/private key pair with the `ssh-keygen` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to give my credentials, username and password, and rlwrap saves them in ~/.config/rlwrap/git_history

Are you certain `rlwrap` indeed saves your *password* in its history file? By design, input that isn't echoed back is *never* put in the history list (in such a case, `rlwrap` will echo your keystrokes as `****`) I checked it, and, on my system at least, this is what happens with `git push` as well.

If you really see your password in the history file, please file a bug at `rlwrap`s [GitHub site](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I probably made a mistake and pasted my password in the username field, because I can't reproduce anymore. Now, it only saves the username, except if I use `c-o`. If I find a bug I will report it on github next time, but I don't think there's any problem, just a wrong manipulation on my part.

Answer (score 3):

I think I've just found a way to prevent the current input line to be saved. From `man rlwrap`:

```
SPECIAL KEYS
   Control + O
          Accept the current line, but don't put it in the history list. This action has a readline command name
          rlwrap-accept-line-and-forget
```

So, instead of validating a line with `Enter`, if I do it with `C-o`, it shouldn't be saved.

---

Maybe I could also use the `-g` option, but I'm not sure I could build a regex describing a password, without describing an ordinary input at the same time:

```
       -g, --forget-matching regexp
          Forget  (i.e.  drop  from history list) all input lines that match the POSIX 1003.2 regular expression
          regexp.  The match is always case-insensitive. regexp may be an ordinary string. For more about  regu‐
          lar expressions, see  regex (7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the default history file with rlwrap's `-H` option.

e.g. `alias gp='rlwrap -H /dev/null git push'`

Comment: Newer (>= 0.43) `rlwrap` may notice that `/dev/null` is not owned by the current user, and complain ([here's](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/issues/39) why). One can silence those complaints with the `-n` (`--no-warnings`) option.